# CSS or Browser issue with a position: fixed while jquery script

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is [codepen example](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/NxKobz). Scroll down to tab block. If you scroll top it adds class 'sticked' and if it reaches bottom of parrent element it gets 'sticked2' class. The issue is: when you set `top: 0` it works perfect. But when you set the 'sticked' class with `top: 1px` or more, it bugges (?) and script stops working. Why is it so? 
**UPD**
Added link to codepen to understand the issue.

```js
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  var labels = $('.forlabels'),
    labelsSec = $('.forlabels-section'),
    bottomOfLabels = labels.outerHeight() + labels.offset().top,
    bottomOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.outerHeight() + labelsSec.offset().top,
    topOfLabels = labels.offset().top,
    topOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.offset().top,
    isAboveTopSec = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabelsSec,
    isAboveTop = $window.scrollTop() < topOfLabels,
    isBelowTop = $window.scrollTop() >= topOfLabels,
    isBelowBottom = bottomOfLabelsSec <= bottomOfLabels;


  if (!isAboveTopSec && ((isBelowTop && !isBelowBottom) || isAboveTop)) {

    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked')
      .removeClass("sticked2")
      .text("Sticked");
  } else if (isBelowBottom) {

    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked2')
      .removeClass('sticked')
      .text("Scrolled Below Bottom");
  } else {

    $('.forlabels')
      .removeClass('sticked sticked2')
      .text("Not sticked ");
  }


});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one-half {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.one-half {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 45%;
  flex: 1 45%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 45%;
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
.fbox {
  height: 1800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.forlabels-section {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.forlabels {
  height: 100px;
  background: #777;
}
.forlabels,
.forlabels-section {
  width: 200px;
}
.sticked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: inherit;
}
.sticked2 {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fbox">

  <div class="forlabels-section">
    <div class="forlabels">Untouched Column</div>
  </div>

  <div class="one-half columned">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @NeedHate Here it is working. Where you see bug? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMJZRP

Comment: @ketan The bug is the that relative element is gray, not the whole left side block.

Comment: @NeedHate Sorry didn't get it. Can give display bug in the image/screenshot?

Comment: @ketan added code snippet. The relative element is green. Now it works fine. And try to change in class sticked  top: 10px;. And you will see the issue. Also see it on fullscreen.

Comment: If you want the column to be full height when the window gets to XYZ coordinate, why not just put `height: 100%` on the `.sticked` class?

Comment: @staypuftman, I dont need it to be full height. In code snippet it works perfect. BUT when you change in CSS in class "sticked" top: 10px the script stops to work, and the grey block falls down through green block as it is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/b57j0cu4/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that by adding the `top` on the element , you also need to recalculate the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` based on the top edge added for comparison between  with the other calculated variables.

**CSS :**

```
.sticked{
  position: fixed;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: inherit;
}
```

**JS :**

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {

  var windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop(); // created a variable for $window.scrollTop() value.
  if($('.forlabels').hasClass('sticked')) // check if the element has class 'sticked' which adds the top margin of 1px;
       windowScrollTop++; // if so, add 1 to $window.scrollTop()
  else if($('.forlabels').hasClass('sticked2'))
       windowScrollTop--;

  var labels = $('.forlabels'),
      labelsSec = $('.forlabels-section'),
      bottomOfLabels = labels.outerHeight() + labels.offset().top,
      bottomOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.outerHeight() + labelsSec.offset().top,
      topOfLabels = labels.offset().top,
      topOfLabelsSec = labelsSec.offset().top,
      isAboveTopSec = windowScrollTop < topOfLabelsSec, // replace reference to $(window).scrollTop() with the variable.
      isAboveTop = windowScrollTop < topOfLabels, // replace reference to $(window).scrollTop() with the variable.
      isBelowTop = windowScrollTop >= topOfLabels, // replace reference to $(window).scrollTop() with the variable.
      isBelowBottom = bottomOfLabelsSec <= bottomOfLabels;


  if ( !isAboveTopSec && ((isBelowTop && !isBelowBottom) || isAboveTop)) {

    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked')
      .removeClass("sticked2")
      .text("Sticked");
  } else if (isBelowBottom) {

    $('.forlabels')
      .addClass('sticked2')
      .removeClass('sticked')
      .text("Scrolled Below Bottom");
  } else {

    $('.forlabels')
      .removeClass('sticked sticked2')
      .text("Not sticked ");
  }

});
```

Replace the above js with your js and it would work as expected.